# Symfony voter warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given?

Tags: php, symfony

I have two voters in my Symfony project. The first voter is OK, but the second voter has a warning:

> Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given

Where is the problem?

My messagevoter.php:

```
class MessageVoter extends AbstractVoter
{
    const VIEW = 'view';
    const DELETE = 'delete';


    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    protected function getSupportedAttributes()
    {
        return array(self::VIEW,self::DELETE);
    }

    protected function getSupportedClasses()
    {
        return array('App\RepairBundle\Entity\RepairMessage');
    }

    protected function isGranted($attribute, $message, $user = null)
    {
        // make sure there is a user object (i.e. that the user is logged in)
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return false;
        }

        $authChecker = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');

        switch ($attribute) {
            case self::VIEW:

                if($user->getId() == $message->getUser()->getId())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case self::DELETE:

                if($user->getId() == $message->getUser()->getId())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $message = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('RepairBundle:RepairMessage')->getMyMessage($this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId());

        $authChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

        if(false === $authChecker->isGranted('view',$message))
        {
            throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('Unauthorized access!');
        }

        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $message,
            $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
            self::PAGE/*limit per page*/
        );
        $msgForm = $this->createForm(new RepairMessageType(),new RepairMessage());
        return array(
            'message' => $msgForm->createView(),
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        );
    }
```

Comment: Verify that RepairMessageRepository::getMyMessage returns a single message object as opposed to an array of messages.

Comment: thank you  cerad , my mistake, message return a array not a obj,your words help me a lot!